# How can I compute an upper bound for expectation from CCDF upper bound?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the following setup:

1. $X$ is a non-negative random variable.
2. $t \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$.
3. $a, b, c > 0, d > 1$ are fixed constants.

I know the following bound: For any $\delta \in (0,1)$, there exists $t_0$ such that for all $t \geq t_0$:

$$P(X > \frac{a}{\sqrt{t}} \sqrt{b - \log \delta} + \frac{c}{\delta} d^{-\log^2 t}) \leq 4\delta.$$

Intuitively, this bound says the following. For any small $\delta$, if $t$ is large enough, then with high probability $X$ is small.

I want to use this probability bound to find a bound on $\mathbb{E}[X]$. Here is my attempt:

Let

$$x = \frac{a}{\sqrt{t}} \sqrt{b - \log \delta} + \frac{c}{\delta} d^{-\log^2 t} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{d x}{d \delta} = - \frac{a}{\sqrt{t}\delta} - \frac{c d^{-\log^2 t}}{\delta^2}$$

We can write

$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{x=0}^\infty P(X>x) dx
\leq \int_{\delta = 0}^1  4 \delta (\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}\delta} + \frac{c d^{-\log^2 t}}{\delta^2}) d\delta
= \int_{\delta = 0}^1 \frac{4a}{\sqrt{t}} + \frac{4c d^{-\log^2 t}}{\delta} d\delta,
$$

But the above integral is not finite. Is my approach correct, specifically regarding integrating over $\delta$? Is it possible to compute a finite bound on $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

---

Update:
Here is another approach that gives a different result. Set $\delta = 1/t$ and assume $t \in \mathbb{R}, t \geq 1$. In this case, we have

$$x = \frac{a}{\sqrt{t}} \sqrt{b + \log t} + c t d^{-\log^2 t} \quad 
\\ \Rightarrow 
\quad \frac{d x}{d \delta} = - \frac{a\sqrt{b + \log \delta}}{2t^{3/2}} + \frac{a}{2t^{3/2} \sqrt{b + \log t}} - 2 c \log(d) \log(t) d^{-\log^2 t} = g(t)$$

And the following integral is finite

$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{t=1}^\infty \frac{4}{t} g(t) dt < \infty.$$

Which approach is correct?

Comment: It is impossible to obtain an upper bound on $E[X]$ based on the given information, which seems only that $X>0$ and $P[X>z]\leq \epsilon$  for some given constants $z>0$ and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.  $E[X]$ can be arbitrarily large and even infinite, just define $$ X = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} z & \mbox{with prob $1-\epsilon$}\\ (M+z)/\epsilon & \mbox{with prob $\epsilon$} \end{array}\right.$$ where $M>0$ is chosen arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Michael I understand your example. But I'm confused because I can construct an example that just with this information $E[X]$ is finite based on the choice of $z$. Suppose $z = \log 1(/\epsilon)$. Then $E[X] = \int_{0}^\infty P(X>z) dz = \int_{1}^0 \frac{-1}{\epsilon} \epsilon = 1$. Is this calculation correct assuming that we know $X$ is a continuous random variable?

Comment: I do not understand your above comment.  You seem to use $z$ both as a fixed constant and a dummy variable for integration (which is it?).  It is not clear if you are using my 2-valued example for $X$ above (a discrete RV), or not, since  in the end you mention an assumption that $X$ is a continuous random variable. So, I do not know what random variable $X$ you are talking about.  And of course particular examples can be given for which $E[X]$ is small, consider $X=z=1/2$ with probability 1.

Comment: @Michael In my question, $z$ is a function of $\epsilon$ and is not constant (and the inequality is correct for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$). It seems to me that given $X>0$ and $P[X>z] \leq \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, whether $E[X]$ is bounded or not depends on $z(\epsilon)$.

Comment: This is not clear.  Your question states a bound in terms of many variables and never says anything about assumptions on those variables, or if it is really an infinite sequence of bounds that hold for any particular choices of those variables.  For example, it seems to me that your question defines $\delta$ as a constant, but later you suggest we may or may not be able to change $\delta$.

Comment: That bound cannot hold "for all $t \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and all $\delta \in (0,1)$" as taking $t \rightarrow\infty$ implies $P[X>0]=0$ and so $X$ cannot be a positive-valued random variable.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the feedback. I've edited my question to add clarity.